# Combine multiple datasets into a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have multiple queries :

```
1)    select Year , Month, Sum(Stores) from ABC ;

2)     select Year, Month , Sum(SalesStores) from DEF ; 

3)     slect Year, Month, Sum(Products) from FGH;
```

I want a result like :

```
Year, Month , Sum(Stores), Sum(SalesStores), Sum(Products)
```

I tried  Full Outer Join  with a query that looks something like this :

```
SELECT ISNULL(x.[Year], y.[Year]) AS [Year],
ISNULL(x.[Month], y.[Month]) AS [Month],
x.Sum_Stores,
y.Sum_SalesStores,
z.Sum_products
FROM (select Year , Month, Sum(Stores) AS Sum_Stores from ABC ... GROUP BY [Month]) AS x
FULL OUTER JOIN (select Year, Month , Sum(SalesStores) AS Sum_SalesStores from DEF ... GROUP BY [Month]) AS y
    ON x.[Year] = y.[Year] AND x.[Month] = y.[Month]
FULL OUTER JOIN (select Year, Month , Sum(products) AS Sum_products from FGH ... GROUP BY [Month])  AS z
ON y.[Year] = z.[Year] AND y.[Month] = z.[Month]
```

The problem is that , ABC has data only for certain months, DEF has data for different months and FGH has data again for different months.

When I run my above query , I get a lot of nulls and 0's.

Can anyone correct me as to whats wrong with the query or tell me a solution that works for my case.

Comment: your code does not contain a `UNION`.

Comment: thanks for the correction its full outer join

Comment: `select Year, Month , Sum(SalesStores) from DEF ` should not execute. Are you missing a GROUP BY?

Comment: I do have a group by month in my original query . I thought I would simplify it and didnt add the "group by month"

Comment: Your full join query wasn't far off. I didn't see there was already an answer so I added a working example of this for you reference. Notice the `coalesce` instead of `isnull` and the `or` in the join clause of the third table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to get this information. This example has a short setup to demonstrate this solution in action.

```
CREATE TABLE #ABC([Year] INT, [Month] INT, Stores INT);
CREATE TABLE #DEF([Year] INT, [Month] INT, SalesStores INT);
CREATE TABLE #GHI([Year] INT, [Month] INT, Products INT);

INSERT #ABC VALUES (2013,1,1);
INSERT #ABC VALUES (2013,1,2);
INSERT #ABC VALUES (2013,2,3);

INSERT #DEF VALUES (2013,1,4);
INSERT #DEF VALUES (2013,1,5);
INSERT #DEF VALUES (2013,2,6);

INSERT #GHI VALUES (2013,1,7);
INSERT #GHI VALUES (2013,1,8);
INSERT #GHI VALUES (2013,2,9);
INSERT #GHI VALUES (2013,3,10);


SELECT
     T.[Year]
    ,T.[Month]
    -- select the sum for each year/month combination using a correlated subquery (each result from the main query causes another data retrieval operation to be run)
    ,(SELECT SUM(Stores) FROM #ABC WHERE [Year]=T.[Year] AND [Month]=T.[Month]) AS [Sum_Stores]
    ,(SELECT SUM(SalesStores) FROM #DEF WHERE [Year]=T.[Year] AND [Month]=T.[Month]) AS [Sum_SalesStores]
    ,(SELECT SUM(Products) FROM #GHI WHERE [Year]=T.[Year] AND [Month]=T.[Month]) AS [Sum_Products]
FROM (
    -- this selects a list of all possible dates.
    SELECT [Year],[Month] FROM #ABC
    UNION
    SELECT [Year],[Month] FROM #DEF
    UNION
    SELECT [Year],[Month] FROM #GHI
) AS T;
```

EDIT:
This can be wrapped up in parametrized stored procedure as requested:

```
-- Call proc like this

--EXEC [getMyReport]; -- params are not required, these will default to NULL if not specified.
--EXEC [getMyReport] @Year=2013; -- all 2013 data, all months
--EXEC [getMyReport] @Month=1; -- all January data, from all years
--EXEC [getMyReport] @Year=2013, @Month=2; -- Feb 2013 data only.

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getMyReport]
     @Year INT = NULL -- default to NULL, this makes the param optional when you exec the procedure.
    ,@Month INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
         T.[Year]
        ,T.[Month]
        -- select the sum for each year/month combination using a correlated subquery (each result from the main query causes another data retrieval operation to be run)
        ,(SELECT SUM(Stores) FROM #ABC WHERE [Year]=T.[Year] AND [Month]=T.[Month]) AS [Sum_Stores]
        ,(SELECT SUM(SalesStores) FROM #DEF WHERE [Year]=T.[Year] AND [Month]=T.[Month]) AS [Sum_SalesStores]
        ,(SELECT SUM(Products) FROM #GHI WHERE [Year]=T.[Year] AND [Month]=T.[Month]) AS [Sum_Products]
    FROM (
        -- this selects a list of all possible dates.
        SELECT [Year],[Month] FROM #ABC
        UNION
        SELECT [Year],[Month] FROM #DEF
        UNION
        SELECT [Year],[Month] FROM #GHI
    ) AS T
    WHERE
        -- if the param IS NULL, then it will not apply filtering
        -- if the param is specified, then it will filter by year or month
        (@Year IS NULL OR T.[Year]=@Year)
        AND
        (@Month IS NULL OR T.[Month]=@Month)
    ;
END
GO
```

Comment: Hey Thanks !! , I have two seperate columns Year & Month , instead of the date (MyDate).. Could you tell me how I need to modify your query to work in my case ?

Comment: Revised answer to use YEAR & MONTH as separate INT fields.

Comment: Great !! Is there a way I can pass an arguement for Month and year and see the results only till that month ?? Right now it displays data for all the months of the year . +1 and marked as answer ..

Comment: Nice, if performance matters you may want to try my version as it only hits the tables once, it will likely end up running slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
   select x,y,z from tableA
   UNION
   select x,y,z from tableB
   UNION
   select x,y,z from tableC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use union alls and a group by to do it instead:

```
    select year, month, sum(stores) as sumStores, sum(salesStores) as sumSalesStores, sum(products) as sumProducts
    from (
        select year, month, stores, salesStores = null, products = null
        from ABC

        union all

        select year, month, stores = null, salesStores, products = null
        from DEF

        union all

        select year, month, stores = null, salesStores = null, products
        from FGH
    ) x
    group by year, month;
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be clearer to use an approach like:-

```
select 
    Year, 
    Month, 
    sum(Stores) as Stores, 
    sum(SalesStores) as SalesStores, 
    sum(products) as products
from (
    select Year, Month, Stores, 0.00 as SalesStores, 0.00 as products
    from ABC ...
    union all
    select Year, Month, 0 as Stores, SalesStores, 0 as products
    from DEF ...
    union all
    select Year, Month, 0 as Stores, 0 as SalesStores, products
    from FGH ...
) source
group by Year, Month
```

The first `select` statement in the derived table defines its structure - and you may need to `cast` the placeholder columns in that statement to types of the correct precision and scale to allow the data from subsequent `union`s to not lose any precision.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using full joins:

```
select
     coalesce(ABC.Year,DEF.Year,FGH.Year) as Year
    ,coalesce(ABC.Month,DEF.Month,FGH.Month) as Month
    ,ABC.Stores
    ,DEF.SalesStores
    ,FGH.Products
from (
    select Year , Month, Sum(Stores) as Stores from ABC group by Year , Month
) ABC
full join (
    select Year, Month , Sum(SalesStores) as SalesStores from DEF group by Year , Month
) DEF
    on DEF.year = ABC.Year
    and DEF.Month = ABC.Month
full join (
    select Year, Month, Sum(Products) as Products from FGH group by Year , Month
) FGH
    on (FGH.year = ABC.Year
    and FGH.Month = ABC.Month)
    or (FGH.Month = DEF.Year
    and FGH.Month = DEF.Month)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e29af/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could union the multiple sets like this:

```
SELECT Year, Month, 'Stores' AS Src, Stores AS Value FROM ABC
UNION ALL
SELECT Year, Month, 'SalesStores',   SalesStores     FROM DEF
UNION ALL
SELECT Year, Month, 'Products',      Products        FROM FGH
```

then [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) them with aggregation:

```
SELECT
  Year,
  Month,
  Stores,
  SalesStores,
  Products
FROM (
  SELECT Year, Month, 'Stores',      Stores      FROM ABC
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Year, Month, 'SalesStores', SalesStores FROM DEF
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Year, Month, 'Products',    Products    FROM FGH
) AS s (Year, Month, Src, Value)
PIVOT (
  SUM(Value) FOR Src IN (Stores, SalesStores, Products)
) AS p
;
```

Or it might be more efficient to first aggregate the results, then union the aggregated sets, then PIVOT:

```
SELECT
  Year,
  Month,
  Stores,
  SalesStores,
  Products
FROM (
  SELECT Year, Month, 'Stores',      SUM(Stores)      FROM ABC
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Year, Month, 'SalesStores', SUM(SalesStores) FROM DEF
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Year, Month, 'Products',    SUM(Products)    FROM FGH
) AS s (Year, Month, Src, Value)
PIVOT (
  MAX(Value) FOR Src IN (Stores, SalesStores, Products)
) AS p
;
```

As the PIVOT syntax requires the use of an aggregated function, we can use one that simply preserves an already aggregated value (in this case it was MAX).